# encountering an error in omnetpp project building

Tags: c++, ubuntu-16.04, omnet++, inet

I am working on omnet++ project called mfogsim. I download it from github https://github.com/rtqayyum/mFogSim , in the site they recommend to use omnet ++ 4.6 along with INET 3.6.4
when I do so on windows the project worked correctly, but, for some reason, I need it to work on ubuntu. when i tried to build the project on ubuntu the following error always appeared
[image: Error Image]

**when I open the the NEDFunctions.cc it seems that it defined properly as illustrated in the following image [image]. can any one help me please**

Comment: Could you provide [mcve]?

Comment: It seems like there's a lot of moving parts here, and we won't be able to reproduce his environment to reproduce the problem.  Perhaps it's better for the OP to post his question on the [issues](https://github.com/rtqayyum/mFogSim/issues) part of the github page, to draw attention from the devs?